# How to compute a conditional expectation given a minimum function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with exponential PDF $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$ with $\lambda=1$. 
Also suppose $$U_1=\min(X,t) \quad \text{ and } \quad U_2 = \max(X,t) $$ for $t>0$. How do I compute $E[X|U_i]$ for $i=1,2$?

Here is how I am attempting this problem: $E[X|U_1] = E[X|\min(X,t)]$. Also, from conditional expectations, I know

$$E[X|U_1] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X|U_1}(x|u_1)\,dx$$

I also know from Law of Iterated Expectation $$E[X] = E[ E[ X|U]]$$  Finally, I also know $$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^\infty x e^{-x}dx = 1$$

Therefore $E[ E[ X|U]] = 1$.

After, after this point I am lost.  I'm not sure where I am going with this.

Comment: Let us go back to the basics: if somebody tells you that min(X,t)=t/2, what does that tell you on X? And if somebody tells you that min(X,t)=t, what does that tell you on X?

Comment: @Did For the first one i think it tells me that X < t because you had to output t/2 to satisfy min() condition. For the second one I think it tells me that X > t because t happens to be the minimum.

Comment: The first one tells you much more. When this will be settled, you might want to deduce E(X|min(X,t)=x) for x<t. When this will be done, turn to E(X|A) with A=(min(X,t)=t). First, what is P(A)?

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention." This is wrong. What is true however is that the OP did not care to follow the specific hints given to them in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly observe that $$U_1=\begin{cases} X, & \text{ if } X<t, \\\\ t& \text{ if } X\ge t\end{cases}$$ or equivalently $U_1=X\cdot1_{\{X<t\}}+t\cdot1_{\{X\ge t\}}$. Now it is s
traightforward that $$E[X|U_1=x<t]=x$$ and that $$E[X|U_1=t]=E[X|X>t]$$ But since $$f_{X|X>t}(x|X>t)=\frac{f_X(x)}{P(X>t)}=\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-t}}=e^{t-x}$$ for all $x>t$, you have that $$E[X|U_1=t]=E[X|X>t]=\int_{t}^{\infty}xe^{t-x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}(t+u)e^{-u}du=t+1$$ Hence, $$E[X|U_1]=U_1\cdot 1_{\{U_1<t\}}+(t+1)\cdot 1_{\{U_1\ge t\}}$$ and similarly for $E[X|U_2]$.

---

Note that for any given $t>0$ you have that $$P(U_1=t)=P(X\ge t)=e^{-t}$$ and therefore $$f_{U_1}(u)=\begin{cases}f_X(u), &u<t\\\\e^{-t}, &u = t\end{cases}$$ Hence, by the law of total expectation $$\begin{align*}E[E[X|U_1]]&=\int_{0}^{t}E[X|U_1=x]f_{U_1}(x)dx+E[X|U_1=t]P(U_1=t)\\\\&=\int_{0}^{t}xe^{-x}dx+(t+1)e^{-t}=1\\\\&=E[X]\end{align*}$$